# What is the difference between a rangefinder's projected and reflected framelines?

Tags: viewfinder, rangefinder, framing

In a rangefinder viewfinder, how do reflected framelines work compared to projected framelines?

Answer (score 1):

To quote from post by Brian Sweeney in [a thread with a similar question on rangefinderforum.com](http://www.rangefinderforum.com/forums/showthread.php?t=98638):

> Reflected lines are painted on the viewfinder, such as in the Nikon S3 and Canon P.
>
> Projected lines are overlaid on the viewfinder using a beamsplitter. The Canon 7, Leica M, and Nikon SP are examples. ...